# USB transceiver helps me to update firmware program to microcontroller via USB interface?

Tags: usb, transceiver

I am doing one hobby project, using STM32F103R8T6 Micro controller for my project, I would like to use USB transceiver for this micro controller,  does this helps me to update my firmware program through USB interface or do I need to have separate programmer for uploading firmware to microcontroller.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up terminology so it's unclear what you are really asking. JTAG/SWD is by far the best interface for development. For field updates, either the serial ROM bootloader or an alternate USB-capable one in flash are options. There are USB bootloaders available so you don't have to write one. Many of the more recent STM32 parts have a ROM bootloader which is it itself USB-capable, unlike the '103 which predates that support in ROM, thus requiring that you put an add-on capability in flash if you want it.   A serial bootloader will require a logic level USB-serial adapter...

Answer (score 1):

The USB transceivers are built-in to the STM32F1 series and you don't need an external phy. You can use the USB for programming if you load a bootloader first. ST has tools for loading from the bootloader.

You will either need to use the USART, JTAG or SWD interface to initially load a bootloader or just load the flash.

Here is a tutorial for loading [from the USART](https://medium.com/@paramaggarwal/programming-an-stm32f103-board-using-usb-port-blue-pill-953cec0dbc86)

If not then use your favorite compiler/debugger and the JTAG or SWD inteface with the ST-link programmer