# USB transceiver or Boot loader

Tags: usb, bootloader, transceiver

I am doing one hobby project, using STM32F103R8T6 Micro controller for my project, now I am using JTAG pins to program the controller. I will keep on modifying the firmware for my project, in this case which terminology is helps me to keep on updating my firmware. I am looking just plug and program kind of solution. 
1) USB transceiver 
2)Boot loader

Having USB transceiver is easy option or
Having bootloader is easy option

Comment: You seem to be mixing up terminology so it's unclear what you are really asking.  JTAG/SWD is by far the best interface for development.  For field updates, either the serial ROM bootloader or an alternate USB-capable one in flash are options.  There are USB bootloaders available so you don't have to write one.  Many of the more recent STM32 parts have a ROM bootloader which is it itself USB-capable, unlike the '103 which predates that support in ROM.

Comment: How is this different from your last question? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447900/usb-transceiver-helps-me-to-update-firmware-program-to-microcontroller-via-usb-i

Comment: Delete this question and edit your first question, please read the help center for guidelines on posting.